# How do I create a Debian branch for my project on Launchpad?

Tags: application-development, packaging, launchpad, bazaar

I have a project on Launchpad that consists of a single branch (`trunk`). I would like to create a second branch that contains the Debian packaging for the project (with the intent of creating a build recipe that merges it into the main branch before building).

I've done this before by just pushing a local branch to `lp:~me/project_name/debian`. However, this stacks the branch with `trunk`, which I don't want (it becomes impossible to delete `trunk` without deleting the Debian packaging branch - a restriction that has caused problems before).

What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to create a new, clean branch with bzr init, then copy your files into it.  Then bzr add, commit and push from the new branch.

Comment: I'm afraid it still created a stacked branch.

Comment: Create a separate repository then elsewhere, outside of your project name.  I have numerous junk branches on my username with numerous other debian stuffs (branches named debian-[application])

Answer (score 0):

The stacking is handled on the Launchpad side. Even if you can't remove the trunk later, you can still rename it out of place (and create a new trunk) and hide it by marking it deprecated.

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to nest the "debian" subdirectory with packaging info, use a build recipe pointing to trunk source branch in LP and add a "nest-part" line to add packaging info as it's described in:
https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/SourceBuilds/Recipes

Something like this:

```
# bzr-builder format 0.3 deb-version 1.0+{revno}
lp:bzr-source-branch
nest-part packaging lp:~some-person/some-project/trunk-with-packaging debian debian
```

If the source branch has no compilation/build errors, your nested debian info will take care of packaging.